# Flutter: Inkwell is clashing with another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

All is well until I try and add the inkwell widget. Why can I not put it here? I need to add the onTap().

**ERROR:** Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

```
     body: AnimationLimiter(
       child: ListView.builder(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(_w / 30),
         physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
             parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
         itemCount: 3,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

return InkWell(
           return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(

             position: index,
             delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            
<Missing code here because not needed to understand more about the problem>
                  
                 

                   child: Center(
                     child: Text(
                       mylist[index],
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                       style: GoogleFonts.laila(
                         textStyle:
                         Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                         fontSize: 30,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                         color: Colors.black54,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           );// AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList
           ); //inkwell
```

Comment: the content inside the InkWell must be child, not return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the content inside the InkWell must be child, not return it.

```
body: AnimationLimiter(
   child: ListView.builder(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(_w / 30),
     physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
         parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
     itemCount: 3,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
return InkWell(
       child: AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
         position: index,
         delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),           
               child: Center(
                 child: Text(
                   mylist[index],
                   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                   style: GoogleFonts.laila(
                     textStyle:
                     Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                     fontSize: 30,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                     color: Colors.black54,
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
        )
       ),
      ); //inkwell
```